# python subprocess.call doesn't handle signal correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, signals

(I'm using Python 3.4.2)
I have a script test.py, which handles SIGTERM etc. However, when it's called by some other script, the sig-handling wasn't correct.

This is test.py:

```
#! /path/to/python3
import time
import signal
import sys

def handleSIG(signal, frame):
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
    sys.exit()

for sig in [signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIGHUP]:
    signal.signal(sig, handleSIG)

time.sleep(30)
```

If I just call "test.py" and do "Ctrl+C", then it prints 0,1,...,9 to the console. However, if I call test.py in another script using subprocess.call, only 0 will be printed. For example, here's another script that calls test.py:

```
import subprocess

cmd = '/path/to/test.py'
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Strangely, using subproces.Popen() makes this error go away.

Comment: Popen would also not wait for the process to finish so not sure how that would work at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I ran test2.py from command line and use Ctrl-C to terminate it. For Popen I use "subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()" so it waits for the cmd to finish.

Comment: BTW, from the implementation of subprocess.call(), it makes sense that the signal-handling feature of the child process will be blocked. I'd understand if nothing was printed at all, but it's strange that it prints something (in my case, 0), but not all of them.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: linux (logged in via PuTTy under windows)

Comment: I am **guessing** it sends `SIGKILL` to the child when the parent is closing in the case when parent is waiting for the child to finish (`subprocess.call()`). The reason it prints 0... well meybe it sent something before `SIGKILL` (you could print what), giving the child process a very short chance for cleanup...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The python 3.3 `subprocess.call` implementation sends a SIGKILL to its child if its `wait` is interrupted, which it is by your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (SIGINT -> KeyboardInterrupt exception).

So, you see a race between the child process handling the terminal's SIGINT (sent to the whole process group) and the parent's SIGKILL.

From the python 3.3 sources, edited for brevity:

```
def call(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        try:
            return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
        except:
            p.kill()
            p.wait()
            raise
```

Contrast this with the python 2 implementation:

```
def call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
```

What an unpleasant surprise.  It appears that this behavior was introduced in 3.3 when the `wait` and `call` interfaces were extended to accommodate a timeout.  I don't find this correct, and I've [filed a bug.](https://bugs.python.org/issue25942)

Comment: you could mention a workaround: define your own handler for `signal.SIGINT` in the parent (to avoid `KeyboardInterrupt` exception) or call `Popen().wait()` explicitly (if you don't need the timeout).

Comment: Yes.  I think the OP is already aware of using `Popen` directly.  As for a custom SIGINT handler, what would you have it do?  Presumably the OP wants to use Ctrl-C to send a SIGINT to the entire process group and, importantly, interrupt the `wait`.

Comment: @pilcrow Thank you so much for your explanation. I've replaced `subprocess.call(cmd)` with `subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()` and that solved this problem. And yes my goal is to use Ctrl-C to kill the parent process and make all child processes exit gracefully.

Comment: @pilcrow: nothing (`signal(SIGINT, lambda *a: None)`), you don't need to interrupt `.wait()` if the child process exits on SIGINT (SIGINT is sent to the whole process group already). But if you can eliminate all `.call()` calls (including in 3rd-party code) then `Popen().wait()` might be preferable.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps `os._exit()` would be better in the signal handler.  That'd yield expected behavior — we probably want the parent to terminate, too. Either way a very particular workaround for an unpleasant situation.

Comment: `os._exit()` may prevent a cleanup code to run. It should not be used blindly. There is no indication that OP needs it in this case.

Comment: I don't think I was clear — the OP probably _does_ want the wait to be interrupted.  But, yes, this is moving in to speculative territory.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** This Python-3 regression will be fixed in Python 3.7, via **[PR #5026](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/5026)**.  For additional background and discussion, see [bpo-25942](https://bugs.python.org/issue25942) and (rejected) [PR #4283](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4283).

---

I ran into this issue myself recently.  The explanation given by @pilcrow is correct.

The OP's solution (in the comments) of merely using the Python 2 implementation (`Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()`) doesn't suffice for me, because I'm not 100% sure that the child will respond to `SIGINT` in all cases.  I still want it to be killed -- after a timeout.

I settled on simply re-waiting for the child (with timeout).

```
def nice_call(*popenargs, timeout=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Like subprocess.call(), but give the child process time to
    clean up and communicate if a KeyboardInterrupt is raised.
    """
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
        try:
            return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            if not timeout:
                timeout = 0.5
            # Wait again, now that the child has received SIGINT, too.
            p.wait(timeout=timeout)
            raise
        except:
            p.kill()
            p.wait()
            raise
```

Technically, this means that I'm potentially extending the life of the child beyond the original `timeout`, but that's better than incorrect cleanup behavior.